# Creating multiple requests from same method in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am parsing webpages that have a similar structure to [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-books/id6018?mt=8&letter=A) page.

I have the following two functions:

```
def parse_next(self, response):
    #  implementation goes here
    #  create Request(the_next_link, callback=parse_next)
    #  for link in discovered_links:
    #      create Request(link, callback=parse_link)


def parse_link(self, response):
    pass
```

I want `parse_next()` to create a request for the **Next* link on the web page. At the same time, I want it to create requests for all the URLs that were discovered on the current page by using `parse_link()` as the callback. Note that I want parse_next to recursively use itself as a callback because this seems to me as the only possible way to generate requests for all the **Next* links.

***Next: The link that appears besides all the numbers on the [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-books/id6018?mt=8&letter=A) page**

How am I supposed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator function and loop through 
your links, then call this on the links 
that you want to make a request to:

```
    for link in links:
      yield Request(link.url)
```

Since you are using scrapy, I'm assuming you have link extractors set up. 
So, just declare your link extractor as a variable like this:

```
    link_extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.+'))
```

Then in the parse function, call the link extractor on the 'the_next_link':

```
    links = self.link_extractor.extract_links(response)
```

Here you go:

http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained

Comment: You mean that there should be two yield statements in the `parse_next()` method? One like this: `yield Request(the_next_link, callback=parse_next)` and the other like this: `yield Request(link, callback=parse_link)`?

Comment: You will be using the BaseSpider class instead of CrawlSpider